# Spark Dataframe Join shuffle

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

*Spark version 1.6.0*

I'm using the join function between two dataframes which have 100 partitions, the app is running on a cluster where I'm using 5 cores for each 20 executor with total 100 cores.

My problem is that when I do the join, all the records are computed on one executor, while the other executors are not used as picture below:
[image]

This cause a decrease in performance because all data is computed with one executor against the other 19 executors available.

It looks like spark join "bring" all the record in only one partitions, is there a way to avoid this?

To be sure that it doesn't repartion to 1 I also set this spark property: `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100` indeed the two input dataframe have 100 partitions same as  the output dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

This is because of your data, not because of spark.

Long answer:

In order to perform `join` operation spark need to move data with same keys (values of columns that you're joining on) to the same workers. E.g. if you join column A with column B the rows that contains same values in both tables will be moved to same workers and then joined.

In addition - rows with different keys also might be moved to same node - this depends on  Partitioner that you have. You can read more [here](https://www.talend.com/blog/2018/03/05/intro-apache-spark-partitioning-need-know/) - but the general idea that there are to default partitioners - `HashPartitioner` and `RangePartitioner`. Despite which one is used - it decides on which worker row goes. As an example - if you have RangePartitioner with ranges [0, 5)[5. 7)[7, 10] then keys 1, 2, 3, 4 will all go to same worker. And if you have only these keys in your data - only one worker will be utilized.